# is there a limit for .vue files?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Good morning everyone,

For some time now I've been working/studying on an application written using the Vuejs framework all managed via vue-CLI and its vue.config.js file and I've had a questions that I haven't found on the internet answers and/or someone who can explain them to me:

**How many ".vue" files can an application written in VueJS contain?**

My boss tells me that the application I made weighs too much (78,923,223 bytes) and asked me to decrease the size;
Since he pointed this out to me, I noticed that I actually have 20 .vue files, aren't they too many or are they okay?

I hope I made myself understood also because it's not a simple question, I understand it right away

Comment: There's no limitation in terms of `.vue` files. But you application can be heavier because of its dependencies. 80MB is indeed heavy. You should take a look if your app includes a big file or anything. Take a look at how you can reduce your bundle size.

Comment: Be very aware of which third-party libs you use and how.

Comment: Something like [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) is a good tool for this sort of thing

Comment: Thanks to all for the clarifications and advices also I wanted to warn you that only the .war weighs (78,923,223 bytes) the build that makes vuejs is only (526,930 bytes) I think it's very good in size

thanks also for introducing me to webpack-bundle-analyzer and I learned to use it through the Vue-CLI